# How to convert correctly an Oracle Date field into java.util.Date through JPA?

Tags: java, oracle, date, jpa

I have an Oracle `Date` column in a db table, and fetching this field by,

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dbPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm");
String query = "SELECT T.MDATE FROM MTABLE T";

List<Object[]> resultList = em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
for (Object[] data : resultList) {
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format((java.util.Date) data[0]));
}
```

The "date" part of printed dates are correct but the "time" (ie. hour and second) parts are "00:00" for all of them. However when I checked this field in SQL Developer, the actual "time" parts are different than "00:00". Where is the problem? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I am using,

```
Hibernate-Version: 3.2.5.ga
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Oracle JDBC Driver version 10.2.0.1.0
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0
```

Comment: does this help ? http://www.coderanch.com/t/464371/ORM/java/JPA-Oracle-Date

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469018/jpa-2-0-oracle-date-has-null-time or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6347532/jpa-entity-get-the-hours-minutes-and-sec-from-oracle-date-column

Comment: No the links doesn't help. I am quering natively, so there is no entity class with the `Date` attribute and `@Temporal` annotation in it. Also I am trying to read from DB other than write into it. Put extra info to the question, see the edition.

Comment: I know it's not a solution, but can you query: "SELECT to_char(T.MDATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') FROM MTABLE T" and then convert it in the java back to a date (ie with dateFormat) ?

Comment: Yes I can, and the time parts are read correctly in this situation. But my requirement is to write queries not depending to Oracle only. It should be runnable on SQL Server also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I finally resolved my problem. The cause was the adventure of `Date` (and `Timestamp`) datatype mappings of Oracle jdbc driver through its version timeline. In short, the problem was resolved by upgrading the **ojdbc14.jar** driver to **ojdbc6.jar**. For more info refer to [What is going on with DATE and TIMESTAMP?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#08_01)

In other words, the Oracle `DATE` type is mapped to Java as follows:
**ojdbc14.jar** : DATE `>` java.sql.Date
**ojdbc6.jar** : DATE `>` java.sql.Timestamp
where java.sql.Date has no time parts.

**EDIT 17.03.2012 :**
If there is no chance to upgrade the driver due to other restrictions, then here is workaround for mapping Oracle DATE to java.sql.Timestamp in JPA with Hibernate:

```
String queryStr = "SELECT T.MDATE FROM MTABLE T";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
SQLQuery sqlQuery = (SQLQuery) ((HibernateQuery) query).getHibernateQuery();
sqlQuery.addScalar("MDATE", Hibernate.TIMESTAMP);
List<Object[]> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: This is great. But if want portable solutions, you should also consider to avoid Native queries when possible (i.e. in 99.99% of the situations)