# Oracle function returns date but no time when called via JPQL

Tags: java, oracle, date, jpa, jpql

I have an Oracle function which accepts amongst other things, a date as parameter, and returns a date. The function is like this:

```
FUNCTION my_func(par1 IN DATE, par2 IN NUMERIC) RETURN DATE AS
ret_val DATE;
BEGIN
....
END;
```

I need to call this function in my Java application, and am currently doing so with JPQL. The code is for a web application running on JBoss 5, and looks like this:

```
   Query q = entityMng.createNativeQuery("SELECT MY_FUNC(?1,?2) FROM DUAL");
   java.util.Date now = new Date();
   long param2 = 110L;
   q.setParameter(1, now);
   q.setParameter(2, param2);
   java.sql.Date retSql = null;
   Object obj = q.getSingleResult();
   if (obj != null) {
      retSql = (java.sql.Date) obj;
   }
```

After executing the code the `retSql` variable contains the correct date but has a time = `00.00.000`. I obtain the same behaviour even when using `java.util.Date` as opposed to `java.sql.Date`, as the type for `retSql`.

While investigating this problem I cam across this SO post [How to convert correctly an Oracle Date field into java.util.Date through JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298093/how-to-convert-correctly-an-oracle-date-field-into-java-util-date-through-jpa), but I don't understand how to use "addScalar" in my case.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that the Java Date class has no time part.  Try declaring your 'now' variable as a timestamp and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try returning a TIMESTAMP in your function, not a DATE.  DATE is now only a date in Oracle, and TIMESTAMP is suppose to be used for date/time.  There is a backward compatibility flag you can set in JDBC to control this.

What JPA provider are you using?  EclipseLink should be handling this automatically.

Comment: note that the best match between oracle and java in this domain is arguably TIMESTAMP(3) and java.util.Date, as both have the same precision (up to the millisecond)... If you see that you get java.sql.Timestamp objects during execution, beware! Problems may arise when seeing Timestamp instances as Date (see introduction in javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html))

Answer (score 0):

What about using XMLAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter {

```
// the desired format
private String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    /*few more formats http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-use-simpledateformat-class-formating-parsing-date-and-time/142    */

public String marshal(Date date) throws Exception {

    return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(date);

}

public Date unmarshal(String dateString) throws Exception {


    return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(dateString);

}
```

And then adding it to your Entity; for example

```
private java.util.Date originDate;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
@Column(name = "ORIGIN_DATE", nullable = true)
@XmlElement(namespace = "my-namespace")
public Date getOriginDate() {
    return this.originDate;
}
```

Here is a tutorial that I used to learned about this;
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/04/xmladapter_in_j.html